# Getting the height of an @ContentChild?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vknjr9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcard.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) the `CardHeaderComponent` from the following layout is retrieved with an `@ContentChildren` decorator:

```
  <ng-content select="card-header"></ng-content>
  <ng-content select="card-body"></ng-content>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <ng-content select="card-footer"></ng-content>
```

And this is the decorator that gets the `CardComponentHeader`:

```
  @ContentChildren(CardHeaderComponent) headers: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

And we can log it like this:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.headers.first); //CardHeaderComponent{__ngContext__: 73}
    console.log(this.headers.first.nativeElement); //undefined
  }
```

I'd like the get the height of the header, however when I try to access the `nativeElement` it's `undefined`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the actual component as an input to the `contentChild` so you will get the component reference (component object instead of dom element), you can instead, specifically tell to fetch the `elementRef` which contains height, the below line needs to be changed!

```
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  ContentChildren,
  ElementRef,
  Input,
  QueryList,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import { CardHeaderComponent } from './card-header.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'card',
  template: `
  <ng-content select="card-header"></ng-content>
  <ng-content select="card-body"></ng-content>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <ng-content select="card-footer"></ng-content>
  `,
  styles: [`:host { display:flex; flex-direction:column;}`],
})
export class CardComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ContentChildren(CardHeaderComponent, { read: ElementRef }) //      <---- changed here
  headers: QueryList<ElementRef>; 

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.headers.first);
    console.log(this.headers.first.nativeElement);
    console.log(this.headers.first.nativeElement.offsetHeight);
  }
}
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tirvrg)